# 4 ways DC power connector KPJX-PM-4S mounting method

Tags: dc, connector, mount, mounting-holes

I came across a standard 4-ways DC power connector like the Kycon KPJX-PM-4S, for panel mounting.
What I was not able to find on the producer website nor on the web is a standard method to secure this connector to a panel.
If I have a panel cutout of the shape of the connector (and according to the specifications found in the datasheet) how can I secure it to the panel? 
I got a standard industry stainless steel panel of 1mm thickness.
Should I use screws and nuts on the other end? Or are there specific mounting brackets? Or is the connector supposed to be mounted on a thicker panel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard 1mm stainless (what you use depends on the stress it will need to withstand).

The actual cutouts are fairly simple:

[image: KPJX PM mechanical]

There will be a circular cutout for the main body (I have not downloaded the 3D stuff - available on the website) - the specific information is not on [this print](http://domino2.kycon.com/2013Catalogpage/DC%20Power/KPJX-PM.pdf). Make sure you have at least 0.5mm oversizing. This print is not clear as to whether the keyways are exposed at the outer main connector body.

The seating plane is where the vertical red lines are.

Drill two holes based on the two screwhole centres from the drawing, suitable for self tapping screws (the recommended method, see above) or use a nut and bolt combination - the hole size depends on the specific screw you use.

There is a note on the length of the screw to use.